# How to convert the array of objects into an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code are written in CodeIgniter, as a method of my model.

```
function get_user () {
 $result = $this->db->get('users_table')->result();
}
```

the `$result` is the resulting array of objects as the result of running database query, what is the best way to convert `$result` in an array?

Comment: `$result` is actually already an array, you can `foreach($result as $k=>$v){ echo $v['columnName'];`

Comment: You can confirm the above comment by doing a `var_dump($result);` and see if it starts off with a `array ( ......`

Comment: Have a look at the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html), this explains query results.

Comment: try `result_array() instead of result()`.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `result_array()` function instead of `result()`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
result_array();

function get_user () {
   $result = $this->db->get('users_table')->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

eater you can try

```
function get_user () {
   $result = $this->db->get('users_table')->result_array();
}
```

or just use the basic

```
function get_user () {
 $result = (array)$this->db->get('users_table')->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Codeigniter's function `result_array()`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function get_user () {
   $result = $this->db->get('users_table')->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is convert into array in provided the function in  `result_array()`

Example : `$rs = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();`