# Retrieve query result with Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I use [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to select some record(s) from my table. This is the query:

```
$data['master'] = $this->db->query("select * from 
        (
         select row, c.Nilai,b.Fullname,a.KodePenilaian,d.Description from penilaian_header a 
        left join employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
        left join outlet d on a.Outlet = d.OutletCode
        left join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row, Nilai,KodePenilaianH from penilaian_Detail
        ) c on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH where a.Outlet like '%$outlet%' and Periode like '%$periode%'
        ) nilai 
        pivot
        (
        sum(nilai)
        for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
        ) piv;")->result();
```

And this the result when I run it via MS SQL Management Tools

[image]

now, my problem is to retrieve these `[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]` values. When I do this:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($data['master']);
die();
```

I only get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Fullname] => maya kristiana
            [KodePenilaian] => PE0000001
            [Description] => KIOS ATRIUM3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Fullname] => SHELVIA GITA PUTRI
            [KodePenilaian] => PE0000002
            [Description] => KIOS ATRIUM3
        )

)
```

**Update:**
I found the solution, thanks to @Alex Tartan (see accepted answer below):

I simply changed my `->result()` to `->result_array();`

and the result is now as desired:

[image]

Comment: my problem is to retrieve the [1],[2],[3],[4],[5] fields value

Comment: use foreach($data['master'] as $data ) { echo $data } or $data['master'][0]->Fullname;

Comment: $data['master'][0], $data['master'][1] like seperate array you get

Comment: Still not working. when i try `foreach($data['master'] as $data ) { echo $data; }` i get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: foreach($data['master'] as $data ) { print_r( $data); }

Comment: I found the solution, thanks to alex tartan . thanks to you too Aslam Patel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791535/how-to-convert-the-array-of-objects-into-an-array/35792168#35792168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use

```
->result_array(); // instead of `->result();`
```

Numerical properties for objects are "weird" to say the least.
Plus, there's the hassle of reading them. You'd have to `echo $obj->{1}`
Also, setting them implies the same approach: `$obj->{1} = 'stuff'`

Codeigniter might not do that.

Getting them as arrays will bypass this issue (hopefully)

Comment: @Boby, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

**This is will return All the Records as Array Result:**

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
 echo $row['title'];
 echo $row['name'];
 echo $row['body'];
}
```

Also If you ever need to get a **Single record** then you can use this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
  $row = $query->row(); 

  echo $row->title;
  echo $row->name;
  echo $row->body; 
}
```

Also refer [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) It will help you